# How to get Request Parameter from Context in Play Framework

Tags: playframework-2.0

Hi have the following `routes` file:

```
POST        /user/:id           controllers.Application.updateUser(id: Long)
```

Is there an easy way to get the value from the `Http.Context`? The `context.request().queryString()` is always empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`context.request().queryString()` only returns query string parameters, whereas you're putting the `id` in the path.  If you want to get it, you have to extract it out of path yourself, eg:

```
long id = Long.parseLong(context.request().uri().substring(
    context.request().uri().lastIndexOf('/') + 1));
```

Comment: THX, I thought there was a simpler solution.

Comment: Nice to see you at stackoverflow, James!

Answer (score 0):

```
context.request()._underlyingRequest().getQueryString(<ID>)
```

Comment: While this code-only post might answer the question, please add an explanation of why it does so. This will help future readers evaluate the answer for their situation.